# Sonarqube parameters for multimodule, multilanguage Maven project

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I have a Maven multimodule, multilanguage project, with below file structure

```
├── server (Java)
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── main
│   │   ├── tests
├── tests (Java)
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── main
│   │   ├── tests
├── frontend (Typescript)
│   ├── component
│   │   ├── apps
│   │   │   ├── submodule1
│   │   │   ├── submodule2
```

They are declared in the root pom.xml, I want SonarQube to pick up all of the modules, but when I explicitly add `frontend/component/apps` to `sonar.sources`, then some fictional paths are created during Sonar scan, for example `***\frontend\component\server\src\main`, which crashes the scan.

When I tried to split the project in modules with `sonar.modules` then Sonar seems to scan `server\src\main` for all the modules, which are ignored, then I'm getting error about scanning files multiple times is not allowed.

How can I make it work?